# Does a Larger Dual Value corresponds to a Smaller Primal Value?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

I am confused about the relationship between primal and dual. I know in some cases we get optimal values of two equal to each other. But are there any relation between solutions to Primal and solutions to Dual? Can we convert one to another? If so, does a better dual solution always correspond to a better primal solution?

Comment: The dual value is a lower bound on the primal value.

Comment: @NicNic8 Thanks, although I know this result. Instead of the value of objectives, I want to know more about relationship between primal and dual solutions.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for may be the the ***Strong Duality theorem***. It says the following (cited from *linear programming Robert J. Vanderbei*)

> If the primal problem has an optimal solution,
>   $$
> x^* = (x_1^*,x_2^*, \dots,x_n^*)
> $$
>   then the dual also has an optimal solution
>   $$
> y^* = (y_1^*,y_2^*, \dots,y_m^*)
> $$
>   such that 
>   $$
> \sum_j c_jx_j^* = \sum_i b_iy_i^*
> $$

The idea is that as the simplex method solves the primal problem, it also implicitly solves the dual problem. Together with [***the Weak Duality theorem***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_duality), we know the following
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
& \text{infeasible} & \text{has an optimal solution} & \text{unbounded} \\
\hline
\text{infeasible} &\checkmark & \text{impossible}&\checkmark \\
\hline
\text{has an optimal solution} &\text{impossible}&\checkmark& \text{impossible} \\
\hline
\text{unbounded} &\checkmark & \text{impossible}&\text{impossible}
\end{array}

Another theorem is the ***Complementary Slackness***:

> Suppose that $x = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ is primal feasible and that $y = (y_1,y_2,\dots,y_m)$ is dual feasible. Let $(w_1,w_2,\dots,w_m)$ denote the corresponding primal slack variables, and let $(z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n)$ denote the corresponding dual slack variables. Then $x$ and $y$ are optimal for their respective problems iff
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> &x_jz_j = 0 \quad for\ j = 1,2, \dots, n \\
> &w_iy_i = 0 \quad for\ i = 1,2, \dots, m 
> \end{align*}
> $$

It provides an alternative way to verify the optimality.

The extension of this will be the ***Strictly Complementary Slackness***:

> We can always find a pair of primal and dual feasible solutions which satisfy: for each $i$ and $j$
>
> 1. Exactly one of $x_j$ and $z_j$ is nonzero
> 2. Exactly one of $w_i$ and $y_i$ is nonzero

One more thing is that other than the *Strict Complementary Slackness*, you can prove the following

> Consider the following linear program problem:
>   \begin{align*}
> (P) \quad &\text{min} \quad &&c^Tx \\
> &\text{s.t.} \quad &&Ax = b \\
> & &&x \geq 0
> \end{align*}
>   and its dual problem is 
>   \begin{align*}
> (D) \quad &\text{min} \quad &&b^Ty \\
> &\text{s.t.} \quad &&y^TA \leq c^T \\
> \end{align*}
>   Assume that both the $(P)$ and $(D)$ have optimal solutions. There exist optimal solutions to $(P)$ and to $(D)$ such that
>   $$
> x_i^*(c_i-y^{*^T}A_i) = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad x_i^* + (c_i-y^{*^T}A_i) > 0
> $$
>   for every $i = 1,2, \dots, n$.

Side note: If you have a primal dictionary, you can use the *negative transpose property* to obtain the dual dictionary. However, I don't know if there is a formula to covert one feasible solution exactly to the other one.

Comment: That would answer the relation between primal optimal sol and dual opt sol. What if when they are not optimal, do we still get any relations between them? In particular, do we know if $d_2$ is a better dual solution that $d_1$. Does the corresponding (if we can convert between dual and primal solutions) $p(d_2)$ is better than $p(d_1)$?

Comment: @NSSM What do you mean by "a better dual solution"?

Comment: @NSSM As far as I know, if when they are not optimal, the relation between them will be the weak duality theorem, as stated in the comment. From the weak and strong duality theorems, you know something like if one is infeasible, the other one must be infeasible or unbounded.

Comment: Your dual must be "max." The dual word comes from this idea: "One is a problem of minimizing and the other maximizing.". Here, you are increasing the duality gap between the problems since if $x$ is feasible for (P) and $y$ for (D), then $c^{T}x - b^{T}y = c^{T} x - (Ax)^{T} y = x^{T}(c - A^{T} y ) \geq 0.$ Hence, by minimizing $ b^{T}y$, you increase the gap. In order to reduce the duality gap, you need to maximize $b^{T}y$.

Comment: By the way, how can I prove that there exists a solution that satisfies the Strictly Complementary Slackness property?. It must be something related to the Farkas' Lemma.

Comment: I asked, "How can I prove that a solution exists that satisfies the Strictly Complementary Slackness property?" I discovered this theorem, called the Goldman-Tucker theorem, some time ago. The proof is quite involved. It involves analyzing all the solutions to the linear programming problem. The theorem's proof can be found in the text Primal-Dual Interior-Point Methods by Stephen J. Wright. I am not sure it has much to do with the Farkas' Lemma, but it is certainly related.